# Necesito ayuda para solucionar error de la tabla mutante

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Tengo el siguiente trigger

```
create or replace trigger Overwrite 
before insert on Comments 
Compound trigger 
declare

begin for each row 
declare
num number; 
begin

select count('x') into num
from comments
where title = :new.title 
and director = :new.director
and club = :new.club
and nick = :new.nick;

if num != 0 then
    delete from Comments
    where title = :new.title 
    and director = :new.director
    and club = :new.club
    and nick = :new.nick;
end if;
end;
```

Y cuando hago una insercion masiva me produce el error de tabla mutante

```
insert into Membership(nick, club, mentor, type, req_date, inc_date, end_date, req_msg, acc_msg) values('davina', 'Fellowship of the Correct', 'adalbi', 'I', sysdate-2, sysdate, null, 'sdfghjhgfd', '23456543dcvbh'); 
insert into Proposals values ('O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'Fellowship of the Correct', 'davina', sysdate, 'asdkhaskd', 'lakshndlkjasdlkjasdfhasdjklhasdfjhkladfsjlhjklashjklds'); 
insert ALL 
    into comments (club, nick, msg_date, title, director, subject, message, valoration) values ('Fellowship of the Correct', 'ecp', sysdate-3, 'O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'asd', 'adsfasdfasdf', 10)
    into comments (club, nick, msg_date, title, director, subject, message, valoration) values ('Fellowship of the Correct', 'ecp', sysdate-2, 'O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'asd', 'adsfasdfdfghdfghasdf', 10)
    into comments (club, nick, msg_date, title, director, subject, message, valoration) values ('Fellowship of the Correct', 'ecp', sysdate-1, 'O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'asd', 'adsfasdfwertwerasdf', 10)
    into comments (club, nick, msg_date, title, director, subject, message, valoration) values ('Fellowship of the Correct', 'ecp', sysdate, 'O', 'Tim Blake Nelson', 'asd', 'adsfasdewrbtvwfasdf', 10)
select * from dual;
```

El problema es que al hacer una insercion simple no tengo problema de tabla mutante, pero cuando se hacen inserciones masivas ocurre el error de la tabla mutante, el cual no veo muy bien por que ocurre y tampoco veo como solucionarlo, si alguien sabe y me podria explicar como solucionarlo y por que ocurre seria bueno.

Gracias

Comment: Olvida el trigger, haz primero `DELETE` (si no hay registros nada borrará) y después el `INSERT`.

Comment: @Sal El problema es que es un trabajo de la universidad que me piden implementar este trigger

Comment: Entonces intenta de igual manera borrar sin hacer antes el conteo.

Comment: @Sal es imposible, porque es para sobreescribir un comentario y de esa manera compruebo si la persona ha comentado antes, si es asi borro su comentario y ya se inserta despues

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Comment: @TheImpaler ORA-04091: la tabla fsdb151.comments esta mutando, puede que el disparador/la funcion no puedan verla

Comment: Luego de hacer DML que modifica una tabla en Oracle debes poner `COMMIT` (para guardar los cambios) o `ROLLBACK` (para deshacerlos).

Comment: Lo primero es borrar los datos y luego insertar, o primero mirar si hay datos y actualizar. No tiene sentido que al momento de insertar se borre información de la tabla, es en contra de las buenas prácticas.

Comment: Cuál versión de Oracle?